# I'd like to know how to change pages in Form Post

Tags: forms, variables, post

I'd like to know how to change pages by putting some in Forms by Post way.

http://www.aldoshoes.com/us/women/shoes/flats

in this page

How do I move to page 2 by putting some variabels in URL?

Please help me out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not possible because it seems to me that the server does not handle GET parameters in the http request.
However it is possible to achieve this using POST parameters, either programmatically or using a plug-in for Chrome/Firefox (see [Super User question](https://superuser.com/questions/345034/google-chrome-extension-to-submit-post-get-requests)).

The server accepts the following parameters:

```
formAction:
startRow:1
rowsperPage:12
flagID:
seasonID:
dimensionID:
sizeID:
colorID:
colorGroupID:
itemCategoryLevel1:1100
itemCategoryLevel2:1101
itemCategoryLevel3:1120
itemCategoryLevel4:
styleID:
styleDescription:
keywords:
alternateDescription:
descriptionDetail1:
descriptionDetail2:
descriptionDetail3:
onsale:N
sortBy:
itemFamilyID:
heelHeight:
```

To get to the second page of the shop you can set the parameter `startRow` to 13:

```
startRow:13
rowsperPage:12
```

Comment: thank you so much. you saved me. but i put ".../flat?startRow=13&rowsperPage=12 , did not working. Please!

Comment: Parameters which are passed through the url are called GET parameters, but in your case they are not handled by the server side script. You have to use POST parameters to do what you want. POST parameters are not visible in the url, they are sent to the server through the http request. As I have already mentioned you have to do that programmatically OR you use a browser plug-in to set POST parameters. Please visit http://superuser.com/questions/345034/google-chrome-extension-to-submit-post-get-requests and try it using POST.